# How to autocomplete non-default argument in VS Code

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey in VS Code for autocompleting a statement with a non-default argument?

For example, I need to make 2 plots side-by-side with the same x-axis, so I type

```
axarr = plt.subplots(1,2,sharex=True)
```

While typing that command, IntelliSense tries to complete my code with `sharex=False`. Is there a way to autocomplete my statement with sharex=**True**?
[image: autocomplete]

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Do you really expect there to be separate hotkeys for auto-completing a variable to "true" and to "false"? Maybe the default value could be configured.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wondering! I know it's trivial, but I figured I'd ask. I just transitioned to Python from MATLAB, so I'm new to the world of proper IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

The next release of the Python extension for VS Code -- `2018.1` -- will not auto-complete arguments with their default values.